# What approch for simple text processing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, nlp

I am trying to do some simple text processing in Haskell, and I am wondering what might me the best way to go about this in an FP language. I looked at the parsec module, but this seems much more sophisticated than I am looking for as a new Haskeller. What would be the best way to strip all the punctuation from a corpus of text? My naive approach was to make a function like this:

```
removePunc str = [c | c <- str, c /= '.',
                                 c /= '?',
                                 c /= '.',
                                 c /= '!',
                                 c /= '-',
                                 c /= ';',
                                 c /= '\'',
                                 c /= '\"',]
```

Comment: Well, you can always write `filter (\`notElem\` ".?!-\'\"")`.

Comment: As a beginner, there's really nothing wrong with what you've written, verbose though it be.

Comment: You might find some functions from `Data.Char` useful, such as `isPunctuation`.  Although that probably would catch more characters than you've listed explicitly.

Comment: For this sort of manipulation of short texts you might find some of the functions in the excellent [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.3/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) package are useful and friendly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply write your code:

```
removePunc = filter (`notElem` ".?!-;\'\"")
```

or

```
removePunc = filter (flip notElem ".?!-;\'\"")
```

Answer (score 11):

A possibly more efficient method (O(log n) rather than O(n)), is to use a `Set` (from [Data.Set](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html)):

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

punctuation = S.fromList ",?,-;'\""

removePunc = filter (`S.notMember` punctuation)
```

You must construct the set outside the function, so that it is only computed once (by being shared across all calls), since the overhead of creating the set is much larger than the simple linear-time `notElem` test others have suggested.

Note: this is such a small situation that the extra overhead of a `Set` might outweight the asymptotic benefits of the set versus the list, so if one is looking for absolute performance this *must* be profiled.

Answer (score 4):

You can group your characters in a String and use notElem:

```
[c | c <- str, c `notElem` ".?!,-;"]
```

or in a more functional style:

```
filter (\c -> c `notElem` ".?!,") str
```